# Windows Web Services on Vista/XP

Tags: web-services, windows-7

I was reading up a little on the new [Windows Web Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/nikolad/) feature that is part of Windows 7, and I wondered if anyone knew if it would be available for use on Vista or XP (or Windows 2003 server)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question the answer is [yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd430435%28VS.85%29.aspx):

Its interesting MS are focussing on web services for native code, but also for [devices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa826001%28VS.85%29.aspx) with the WSDAPI and remote management services too.

edit:

turns out that you have to beg Microsoft to use it on [any non-W7 system](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowssdk/archive/2009/10/20/building-web-services-on-windows-with-c.aspx):

> WWS API is available on all versions
>   of Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008
>   R2 and it can also be deployed to
>   Windows XP, Vista, Server 2003 and
>   Server 2008.  The redistributable
>   installers are available on a formal
>   request to wwsredst@microsoft.com 
>   with a brief description of plans for
>   using this runtime and the business
>   contact information for your company.

So, it seems [gsoap](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html) is still the best solution for creating fast, low-memory web services.

Comment: just FYI, there's a nice article about WWS with some speed and resource info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/ee335693.aspx